# dim(x) must have a positive length, yet I can't see the problem

Tags: r

I'm creating a data frame of a deck of cards (1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8). Taking a ggplot but applying a tt=sapply(t,card_2), R gives me an error saying dim(X) must have a positive length. Can anyone help me on this? Thank you

Comment: What did you try to do with [!j==x] ? Because if you are trying to find the values of j which are different of x, the correct line is j ! = x

Comment: k=j[!j==x] is to retain the 9 out of 10 cards, removing the index 'x'

Answer (score 1):

This is failing because of the following lines:

```
  sum_a=apply(a,2,sum)
  min_a=apply(a,2,min)
  sum_b=apply(a,2,sum)
  min_b=apply(b,2,min)
```

The `sum` and `min` functions are aggregating functions. They return a single value over a vector (or matrix). You are asking R to iterate over your `a` and calculate a sum or minimum for each value (which is nonsense). Just do:

```
  sum_a=sum(a)
  min_a=min(a)
  sum_b=sum(b)
  min_b=min(b)
```

Also, you need to make sure `a` and `b` are numeric first.